# Why is sampling distribution = likelihood function? due to the central limit theorem?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, central-limit-theorem, maximum-likelihood

I noticed something peculiar when I define the **binomial distribution**:
$$p(r,n,\theta)=\theta^r(1-\theta)^{n-r} {n\choose r}$$
we can look at this distribution as a function of $r$, the sampling distribution: $s_{n,\theta}(r)=p(r,n,\theta)$, or as the likelihood of $\theta$: $L_{r,n}(\theta)=p(r,n,\theta)$.

What I noticed is that if we set $n$ small, these functions resemble each other somewhat though they are not the same, but when we set n very large, **these functions tend to exactly the same values**: $$s_{n,a}(x)\approx L_{a,n}(x)$$

---

Then I noticed that in the case of the normal distribution $\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac {(x-\mu)^2} {2 \sigma ^2}}$, the sampling distribution and the likelihood of $\mu$ are exactly the same, since we can just swap $x$ and $\mu$.

Of course in the normal distribution this is obvious from the formula, though I never explicitly thought about this in terms of the sampling distribution being equal to the likelihood function.

**But in the case of the binomial distribution, it is not at all obvious to me from the formula why sampling distribution = likelihood function**.

---

**More generally, is there a general principle that the likelihood function and the sampling distributions should equal each other? Is there an intuitive reason why this should be the case?**

Answer (score 2):

Because of the definition of the likelihood function, which is defined as the joint probability of your sample observations (cf. Wackerly,  *Mathematical Statistics With Applications*).

If your observations are independant from each other, then the joint probability is the product of the probabilities (cf. Bayes https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21822/understanding-naive-bayes/21849#21849).

So in the end you just have a product of probability density functions.

But to answer your question, clearly the sampling distribution of a statistic function of your sample is not always equal to the likelihood function. Take for example the normal distribution : the likelihood will be : $$ L(\mu, \sigma^2 ) = f(y_1, y_2, ...,y_n |\mu, \sigma^2) = \left(\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\right)^{n/2}e^{\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\mu)^2}$$ 
Now compare it to the probability density of the sampling distribution of  $\bar{Y},$ the sample mean of  variables $  \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) $ :$$ f(y) = \frac{1}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$